# Diferença entre os operadores -> e :: no php

Tags: php

Quando estou a usar um package qualquer no Laravel deparo-me com a seguinte situação:

```
 TranslatableBootForm::text('Name', 'name')
                        ->placeholder('My placeholder')
```

A minha questão é a seguinte visto que os **::** servem para aceder a métodos ou propriedades e o **->** servem também para aceder a métodos ou propriedades porque que não posso chamar o método assim:

```
TranslatableBootForm->text('Name', 'name')
                            ->placeholder('My placeholder')
```

Pode parecer um pergunta estúpida mas é uma duvida que tenho.

Comment: Porque o método é estático. Então o :: é necessário.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php#language.oop5.static.properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O operador de resolução de escopo `::` serve para acessar atributos e métodos da classe não instanciada em um objeto, por exemplo, abaixo você tem uma Classe (um modelo) não instanciado, ou seja, não é necessário instanciar um objeto chamando um construtor `new Person()`, apenas a chamada direta:

```
<?php

class Person
{
    public static string $name = 'Test';

    public static function getName()
    {
        return 'O nome de Person é ' . self::$name;
    }
}

echo Person::$name;
echo '<br>';
echo Person::getName();
```

**O Código acima irá imprimir:**

```
Test
O nome de Person é Test
```

Se você deixar o código exatamente como está no exemplo acima, mas remover a palavra `static` do atributo `$name` ele dará erro `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Access to undeclared static property: Person::$name...` tanto no `echo Person::$name` como no `echo Person::getName()`. **Um Aviso:** Nesse caso o erro se dará pela tentativa ao acesso de `$name`, e você comentar a chamada `//echo Person::$name` ele irá executar o método normalmente, mas o erro ocorrerá quando o método tentar acessar o `self::$name`.

**Outro exemplo é instanciar a classe em um objeto**

```
<?php

class Person
{
    public string $name = 'Test';

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'O nome de Person é ' . $this->name;
    }
}

$person = new Person();
echo $person->name;
echo '<br>';
echo $person->getName();
```

**O código acima irá imprimir:**

```
Test
O nome de Person é Test
```

Veja que o resultado é o mesmo, embora nesse segundo caso você instanciou a classe, ou seja, criou um objeto da classe. A prova disso é a chamada do `new` que irá fazer a chamada ao método construtor da classe, no caso o `__construct()` mesmo que ele esteja omitido.

**Repare:**
No segundo exemplo, por ser um objeto troca-se o operador de resolução de escopo `::` por acesso ao atributo/metodo da classe `->`
Outra diferença está na chamada do atributo por exemplo, o método `static` *getName()* utilizava o `self::$name` utilizando até o dólar no prefixo do atributo, já o método "normal" (sem abstract, static, etc.), você chama através do `$this` que se refere à "essa classe instanciada", ou seja o próprio *OBJETO*